# Evaluate improper integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sec^2x-\sec x \tan x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Evaluate the improper integral
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sec^2x-\sec x \tan x)dx$$

I got
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sec^2x-\sec x \tan x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx$$

The singularity occurs at the upper bound $\pi/2$. But, I don't know how to deal with it to evaluate  the integral.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{z\to \pi/2^-}\int_0^z(\sec^2x-\sec x \tan x)\,dx=\lim_{z\to \pi/2^-}[\tan z-\sec z+1]=\lim_{z\to \pi/2^-}\frac{\sin x+\cos x-1}{\cos x}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First of all, $~\tan'x=1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x.~$ Secondly, $~\cos'x=-\sin x.$

Answer (score 0):

To avoid dealing with the singularity at the upper bound $x\to \frac\pi2$, continue manipulating the integrand as follows

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sec^2x-\sec x \tan x)dx\\=&\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1-\cos x}{\sin^2x}dx\\
=& \ \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos^2\frac x2}dx
=\tan\frac x2\bigg|_0^{\pi/2}=1
\end{align}

Comment: How did you get  $$\frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\cos^2\frac\pi2}dx? $$

Comment: $\frac \pi 2$ or $\frac x 2$ ? I think it's a typo.